# How to simply rewrite URL in .htaccess to echo username

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I know there are tons of questions already but looks like i'm missing a step.

I recently added a login/signup form to my website. Users can then fill out a quick bio on their profile.

The issue that i'm facing is that right now, the profile page URL looks like that:

```
"www.example.com/profile.php"
```

How can I edit the .htaccess file so that it looks like:

```
"www.example.com/neil/
```

(neil being the username)

I've tried to add this to my .htaccess file but it didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/?name=$1 [L]
```

fiy, i'm working on localhost.

**Just to be clear:** my htaccess file should have no extension right (should't end with .txt) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The rule `(.+)/` matches a string of one or more characters that ends with a slash, but returns the string without the end slash.

Changes this: `http://www.example.com/neil/`
To this: `http://www.example.com/profile.php?name=neil`

Changes this: `http://www.example.com/ne/il/`
To this: `http://www.example.com/profile.php?name=ne/il`

**EDIT:**

As suggested by sgroves:
Since names will probably not contain slashes, you can only match strings that don't contain slashes like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: don't you mean `([^/]+)/`?

Comment: @sgroves That probably makes more sense, given that a name will probably not contain a slash. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @showdev Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. Nothing changes in the URL.  Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: @NeilG. why don't you read about how mod_rewrite works and figure this out yourself? there are TONS of great examples of how to do stuff like this online.